# .NET Core 2.0 AddToRoleAsync - User name is invalid, can only contain letters or digits

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Im working with .NET Core 2.0 MVC and Entity Framework with Individual User Accounts. By default, usernames are the same as email address. I used the following in Startup.cs to create the roles

```
private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    //adding custom roles
    var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
    string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "User" };
    IdentityResult roleResult;
    foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
    {
        //creating the roles and seeding them to the database
        var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
        if (!roleExist)
        {
            roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
        }
    }

    //creating a super user who could maintain the web app
    var poweruser = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"],
        Email = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"]
    };

    string UserPassword = Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserPassword"];
    var _user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Configuration.GetSection("UserSettings")["UserEmail"]);

    if (_user == null)
    {
        var createPowerUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(poweruser, UserPassword);
        if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
        {
            //here we tie the new user to the "Admin" role 
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(poweruser, "Admin");

        }
    }
}
```

And called it from the Configure method in Startup.cs. The roles added just fine, and the role was added to the admin.

However when I try to add a role to a user programmatically using the method `await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, "Admin");` in my ApplicationUsersController I get the error

> User name is invalid, can only contain letters or digits

The .NET Core 2.0 documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x indicates that the "@" and/or "." that may be causing the error are included as valid characters by default in AllowedUserNameCharacters. I'm at a loss of other things to try.

Here is my `ApplicationUsersController` code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class ApplicationUsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ApplicationUsersController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {

        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("Id,Name,Email,IsAdmin,ConcurrencyStamp,SecurityStamp")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {
        if (id != applicationUser.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                applicationUser.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                applicationUser.NormalizedEmail = applicationUser.Email.ToUpper();
                _context.Update(applicationUser);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                if (applicationUser.IsAdmin)
                {
                    var x = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, "Admin");
                    if (!x.Succeeded)
                    {
                        string s = "";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, "User");
                }

            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ApplicationUserExists(applicationUser.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that it `AddToRoleAsync` which is throwing that error? Is it possible that `UserManager.CreateAsync` method is resulting in the error? What is the value of powerUser.UserName when you get to `UserManager.CreateAsync` line?

Comment: Thank you Abhay, it may be. However I wasnt clear on where I was getting the error. It is in my ApplicationUsersController, not in the CreateRoles method.I included the code for that

Comment: Put a breakpoint on _context.Update(applicationUser); This is line where it may be throwing exception. Have you checked what is value of Username property of applicationUser you are trying to update?

Comment: I set a breakpoint, the error is triggered at var x = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, "Admin");

Comment: Check the users name in the database. From looking at the code repo in GitHub, this error can also be thrown if the user name is null or empty for some reason.

Comment: You're not binding the `Username` property in your action method.  It's likely null.  You should be using `UserManager` to load and update the user.  You're not even loading the user into your `DbContext` so `_context.Update(applicationUser); await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` does nothing.

Comment: Thanks Brad - the binding was it. I should have been updating the Username since the email was able to be updated. I added the UserName to the Bind and also added it as a hidden field in my view and it works.